# Disable tabs activation when scrolling PyQT QTabWidget

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt5

I have QTabWidget in my PyQT5 application on linux. Here is a [demo](https://youtube.com/shorts/qQJMsGXHt3s?feature=share)

I have problem with scrolling that you can see in my video. When i scrolls througth tabs by using middle mouse or touchpad tabs activating. How can i disable it? I can`t find some method for this in PyQT documentation or QtDesigner

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this using the usesScrollButtons attribute of the QTabWidget. So something like,

```
tab_widget = QtWigets.QTabWidget()
tab_widget.usesScrollButtons = False
```

Reference: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#usesScrollButtons-prop

Comment: Its not working [demo](https://youtube.com/shorts/OJhx0vzK2qc?feature=share)

Comment: Try tab_widget.setUsesScrollButtons(False)

Comment: it does same...